# Python PEP8 conventions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pep8, pep

I'm a Python beginner, I read pep standards which must follow while programming in python 
http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008

Now I have a doubt. As they have mentioned that you should not put spaces around the equal sign while using keyword argument or a default parameter value in functions or Dict.

For example

**YES**

`def myfunc(key1=val1, key2=val2, key3=val3)`

**NO**

`def myfunc(key1 = val1, key2 = val2, key3 = val3)`

Thats fine but what if I break down these in multiple lines. something like this(when we have many parameters or long name)

`def myfunc(key1=val1, 
            key2=val2, 
            key3=val3)`

In this case, I think, we should put space around the equal sign. am I correct. because these all are about readability but I'm just curious if there is standard for this too. Looking for best practices.

Same thing for Dict.

```
new_dict= Dict(
       key1=val1, 
       key2=val2, 
       key3=val3
)
```

And should I put a comma after last argument in dict unlike example mentioned above, I didn't put a comma after last value (key3=val3)

Comment: Well this is closed as opinion-based, but here's a fact: PEP8 does NOT state that you must follow it while programming in Python, although many people seem to be misled into believing that. PEP8 is the coding standard for the standard set of libraries included with Python. To fully understand what that means, please consider the following: when programming in C, should everyone follow the coding standard used to implement stdlib.c?

Comment: I 100% agree that space around the equal sign is way more readable. And putting trailing commas after the last argument makes coding way easier (reduces random syntax errors), regardless of readability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PEP8 [clearly says](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations):

> Don't use spaces around the = sign when used to indicate a keyword
>   argument or a default parameter value.

You don't need to put white spaces around the equal sign in both cases.

If you are not sure whether your code follows PEP8 standard or not, use [`flake8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) static code analysis tool. It would raise warnings in case of code style violations.

Example:

Consider you have extra whitespaces around the equal signs:

```
def myfunc(key1 = 'val1',
           key2 = 'val2',
           key3 = 'val3'):
    return key1, key2, key3
```

`flake8` outputs a warning for every unexpected whitespace:

```
$ flake8 test.py
test.py:3:16: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
test.py:3:18: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
test.py:4:16: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
test.py:4:18: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
test.py:5:16: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
test.py:5:18: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
```

Comment: I don't think this really responds to the question, although it does also correct another pep8 violation in the code.

Comment: Looks like the OP is just using 8 space indents (or tabs, gasp!) and wasn't trying for styled alignment.

Comment: @msw OP is using 7 spaces in the quoted code.

Comment: Infact @Marcin your answer didn't really responds to my question but this. I just wanted to know which one is correct and this answer told me enough to clear my doubts.
but it didn't answer my last question about comma after last kwarg in dict

Comment: @user3810188 glad it helped. I've edited the answer to make it more specific. Extra comma is definitely not a violation.

Comment: I need One more help. how do I run flake8 for a django project. will it automatically check all directory and subdirectories

Comment: @user3810188 yup, you can run it against a directory too.

Answer (score 6):

> Thats fine but what if I break down these in multiple lines. something like this(when we have many parameters or long name)
>
> ```
> def myfunc(key1=val1, 
>        key2=val2, 
>        key3=val3)
> ```

In the code you give, you are not putting whitespace around the `=`, so you are complying with pep8 in respect of operator spacing (your indentation does not comply with pep8).

In general, you can write your code however you like. If you don't comply with pep8, other people generally won't find your code as easy to read. If you have local standards within your company, that should supercede pep8. If you don't have standards that direct you to violate pep8, your colleagues will likely hate you for breaking pep8.

If you don't have a standard at all, future you will also hate present you.

Answer (score 2):

No.  Don't put spaces around equal signs when declaring kwargs.  Think of it this way: If you are just skimming lines of code, you want to train your eyes to see the difference between the assignment operator used during ordinary program flow (spam = True) and a kwarg, especially if it's on its own line (spam=True).

As for a trailing comma, I have always felt that a trailing comma suggests to a fellow team member or reader that I feel the list, dict, set of args, etc. might be subject to expansion in the future.  If I'm fairly certain that the structure represents its mature state, I remove it.

Comment: at least this answer gives a good reason as to *why* pep8 says x or y instead of merely quoting it